# Difference between place of issue and place from where you leave for the destination

Tags: visas, london, lhr, application-status, new-delhi

I have applied for a British Visa from Singapore but will be flying from new Delhi. Is this likely to pose problems during my travel, like at the London Heathrow Airport?

Comment: No, in itself this is not an issue at all. It happens all the time and IO's understand how the system works :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this likely to pose problems during my travel, like at the London Heathrow Airport?

No. Consider if your flight was from Singapore **via** New Delhi. At LHR, New Delhi is still where you arrived from (directly).

Security, Immigration, Customs, airline staff, shopkeepers, taxi drivers etc don't really care where you came from, though they may ask. And, if it were possible, the same people would care even less where your visa was issued.